# Rock Paper Scissor Lizard Spock Game Not Working

Tags: java

So, when I run this I get to input the values, but after the value is inputted it does not execute the switch statements to tell me who wins. I have not yet put all the cases but I wanted to test it and nothing is happening. I had y being a random value assigned and that was not working, so I just made it human input. I eventually have to make it where the human is playing the computer.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class rock{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x;
        int y;
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
         Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Human player: Enter 0 for rock, 1 for scissors, 2 for paper, 3 for lizard, 4 for spock:");
        x=input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Computer player: Enter 0 for rock, 1 for scissors, 2 for paper, 3 for lizard, 4 for spock:");
        y = input.nextInt();

         switch(x)
            {
                case '0':
                    switch (y)
                    {
                        case '1':
                            System.out.print("Human Wins computer chose scissors!");
                            break;
                        case '2':
                            System.out.println("Human wins computer chose paper!");
                            break;
                        case '0':
                            System.out.println("Draw!");
                            break;
                        case '3':
                            System.out.println("Human Wins with Lizard!");
                            break;
                        case '4':
                            System.out.println("Computer Wins with Spock!");
                            break;
                    }
            }
            switch (x)
            {
                case '1':
                    switch(y)
                    {
                    case '1':
                        System.out.print("Human Wins computer chose scissors!");
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        System.out.println("Human wins computer chose paper!");
                        break;
                    case '0':
                        System.out.println("Draw!");
                        break;
                    case '3':
                        System.out.println("Human Wins with Lizard!");
                        break;
                    case '4':
                        System.out.println("Computer Wins with Spock!");
                        break;
                    }
            }
            switch (x)
            {
                case '2':
                    switch (y)
                    {
                    case '1':
                        System.out.print("Human Wins computer chose scissors!");
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        System.out.println("Human wins computer chose paper!");
                        break;
                    case '0':
                        System.out.println("Draw!");
                        break;
                    case '3':
                        System.out.println("Human Wins with Lizard!");
                        break;
                    case '4':
                        System.out.println("Computer Wins with Spock!");
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why do you have 3 `switch (x)` statements? You should only have 1, and it should have 5 cases.

Comment: You have declared `int x` and then in the `switch` statement your cases are on `char` values. Try `case 1:`.

Comment: please debug your application using breakpoints and inspecting the values of `x` and `y` or at least add a couple of `System.out.println(...)` statements to see which statements you actually reach.

Answer (score 2):

Works after a few corrections :-
1) You dont need to use switch(x) multiple times.
2) x and y are int so case statements should be like case 1 and not case '1'

```
public class Rock {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x;
        int y;
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
         Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Human player: Enter 0 for rock, 1 for scissors, 2 for paper, 3 for lizard, 4 for spock:");
        x=input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Computer player: Enter 0 for rock, 1 for scissors, 2 for paper, 3 for lizard, 4 for spock:");
        y = input.nextInt();

         switch(x)
            {
                case 0:
                    switch (y)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            System.out.print("Human Wins computer chose scissors!");
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            System.out.println("Human wins computer chose paper!");
                            break;
                        case 0:
                            System.out.println("Draw!");
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            System.out.println("Human Wins with Lizard!");
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            System.out.println("Computer Wins with Spock!");
                            break;
                    }

            case 1:
                    switch(y)
                    {
                    case 1:
                        System.out.print("Human Wins computer chose scissors!");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("Human wins computer chose paper!");
                        break;
                    case 0:
                        System.out.println("Draw!");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        System.out.println("Human Wins with Lizard!");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        System.out.println("Computer Wins with Spock!");
                        break;
                    }

            case 2:
                    switch (y)
                    {
                    case 1:
                        System.out.print("Human Wins computer chose scissors!");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("Human wins computer chose paper!");
                        break;
                    case 0:
                        System.out.println("Draw!");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        System.out.println("Human Wins with Lizard!");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        System.out.println("Computer Wins with Spock!");
                        break;
                    }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using characters, not numbers.

When you do this

```
case '1': // uses a character, which has an ascii (thus integer) value of 49
```

is different from this which is like `int x = 1; // integer value of 1`

```
case 1: // uses an integer with value of 1
```

`char` can be auto-cast into an `int` which is what is happening here. It would seem convenient to get a warning when `switch`ing on one type and `case`ing on another, but c'est la vie.